# Declare @outputVariable AS tablename in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anybody please let me know the meaning of the two statements below in TSQL

```
ALTER PROC [list].[UpdateState] 
    (@SK_ListID AS TINYINT, @Sales AS list.sales READONLY)
```

And / OR

```
DECLARE @Out AS list.sales;
```

I am aware that `list.sales` is a table. But I do not see this table existing in our database. When I do a select on `@out` I do get two columns as outputs. How does this work? Where will exactly is the table created? From where is it returning the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Sales AS list.sales READONLY` declares `@Sales` as a *[Table Valued Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)* of the *[User Defined (Table) Type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)* `sales` in the `list` schema.

The other is a declaration of the same type.